# Can I cancel a project and give refund instead?

Tags: project, contract-cancellation

Can I cancel a project and give a refund if I found a better offer,
or can I cancel any project whenever I want, in case I give a refund?

It is known that clients have the right to cancel any offer whenever they want with or without a reason.

Comment: What contract have you signed? What platform are you using (if any)? If you're using a platform, the platform may penalize you if you don't have a good reason for cancelling. You need to read the contract and their terms of services.

Comment: Using Upwork. I was just asking because technically canceling is possible.
and all the contract's public details will be erased after refund.

Comment: Yeah, you really need to read the Upwork terms.

Answer (score 0):

The legality depends on the contract that you signed or agreed to.

The ethics of canceling a project because of a better offer are dubious. You have no guarantee that the second project will last very long. But your reputation in the market will be hurt by not following through on your agreements. Reputation is important for future projects.

If you are worried that a client will cancel, write into the contract a cancellation clause where they have to pay X amount if cancelling prior to accepting the results. Or do the project on an hourly basis where they pay for the work done.